# Options under "flag a comment"

Tags: discussion, comments

- I am flagging this comment as

  - **rude or abusive** *This comment violates our "Be Nice" policy.*
  - **no longer needed** *This comment is obsolete, chatty, or otherwise unnecessary.*
  - **in need of moderator intervention** 
    *A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. Be specific and detailed!*

Why isn't "useless" in this list?  "This comment is useless, adds nothing, and is a waste of everyone's time and energy" would be a good addition to this list.

Answer (score 5):

It's covered by "no longer needed" (you can think the "and it never was" as you click).

Comment: Indeed.  "Useless" and "otherwise unnecessary" are almost synonyms.

Comment: I suppose my gripe is that "no longer needed" is different from "never needed"